# NASM assembly x86: Is it possible to write a loop in a loop? (Need fix for bubblesort)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I encountered some problems with my bubblesort algorithm.

I have (for example):

s db 12h, 63h, 13h, 07h, 52h, 1ah, 2bh, 56h

and I have to sort this in d using lods, stos, and (if necessary) movs functions.

Can you help me out with this? I'll tell you where the problems are.

```
bits 32
global start

extern exit
import exit msvcrt.dll

segment data use32 class=data
s db 12h, 63h, 13h, 07h, 52h, 1ah, 2bh, 56h
    l equ ($-s) 
    d times l db 0
    max dw 00ffh
segment code use32 class=code
start:
    mov ESI, s
    mov ECX, l
    mov EBX, l
    mov EDI, d
    bbs: 
        mov DX, max
        bbs1:
            lodsb ;Problem 1*
            cmp AL, DL
            dec ECX
            jg bbs1
            inc ECX
            mov DL, AL
        loop bbs1
        cld
        mov ECX, EBX
        mov EAX, EDX
        stosb ;Problem 2**
    loop bbs
    push dword 0 
    call [exit]
```

*I didn't have this problem until i modified the length with the correct one

EDITED: its position, I put it originally upper

**It crashed here before the start

Problem 3: I have a part of code which is correct that I used beforehand, but didn't put in here since it isn't technically wrong and I adapted this. The exact code in this sequence has the same problems as the one in my original one.

Thank you in advance and happy coding!

Comment: What's with that weird inner loop? You have a `cmp` immediately followed by a `dec`, followed by a `jg` which relies on flags that are modified by both `cmp` and `dec`.

Comment: Hi there! I was trying to get the minimum out of that list from a certain point and manage my elements, but right after you asked the question I realized that I implemented it wrong and I'd miss on some elements. Still, I can't manage to do a loop in loop using the same register without getting errors, so at least if the algorithm wasn't correct (my case), I'd like to get it error-free,so it can run. Edit: grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a loop in a loop?

Yes. You're almost doing it right.

> (Need fix for bubblesort)

This code is definitely **not** a bubblesort. What you're almost doing is looking for the min/max and storing that in another array, several times over!

> ```
> lodsb ;Problem 1*
> ```

You need to reload `ESI` before the innerloop starts!
Also bring that `CLD` at the top of the program.

> ```
> mov ECX, EBX
> mov EAX, EDX
> stosb ;Problem 2**
> ```

The problem is not `STOSB`, but the fact that you max your iteration counter for the outerloop every time, getting into an infinite loop and consequently crashing...

---

Depending on what exactly it is that you're trying to achieve, this could be a decent innerloop:

```
  mov esi, s
bbs1:
  lodsb
  cmp AL, DL
  jge skip
  mov DL, AL     ; Found a smaller number
skip:
  loop bbs1
```

---

Solve the iteration of the outerloop like:

```
  mov AL, DL
  stosb
  dec ebx
  jnz bbs
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me figure it out. I adapted it in my own style and everything is running smooth!